# momentjs - Parse text in a particular timezone if format is given

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, momentjs, moment-timezone

I have a scenario where I have the format, timezone, and the date text and I want to return a `moment object` such that the date is formed in that timezone:

```
import moment from 'moment';
import 'moment-timezone';

const timezone = 'America/New_York';

const getMoment = (text, format) => moment.tz(text, format, timezone);
const momentObj = getMoment(text, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:ss.SSS');
console.log('momentObj:', momentObj);
```

When I do this, console.log shows this:

[image]

Object

The zone object is set correctly to America/New_York, but isUTC is set to true. How can I get rid of that?

Comment: The underscore before the property name means "don't look at me or make any assumptions based on my value; for internal use only". In other words, unless you're actually having issues with the `moment` object, don't worry about those properties.

Comment: @Heretic Monkey ... So I just have to look at Zone object to see that this moment obj is in the timezone which I need correct? That the date text I sent in, for e.g. 2018-06-05 10:00:00 AM will be infact 10 AM New York time on 5th June 2018?  And not in 10 AM UTC.

Comment: Just output the date: `momentObj.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:ss.SSS")` and make sure it matches what you expect. Because what timezone a date is in is immaterial until you do something with it.